# How to "force" json_encode() to turn non-utf8 strings into null?

Tags: php, utf-8, null, json

On the server a website is running (PHP 5.5.9.) - when I run `json_encode()` on an object with non-UTF8 characters - it returns `false`.

But locally - PHP 5.3.10 - `json_encode()` onthe same data returns the JSON object,just turned the non-UTF8 characters into `null`.

I want to achieve the same behavior on the server ... hopefully - without downgrading the PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively walk your array/object and use `utf8_encode()` (or set it to null) on any value where `mb_check_encoding()` returns false.

Comment: Yes ... and I used a slightly modified version of this gist - https://gist.github.com/oscar-broman/3653399 - and it's working. But - I had to modify the PHP framework the website is using ... and this is something I was really trying to avoid ... ... ... ... but anyway, this approach does the job for now :) ...

Comment: @peshohristov You should file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the constant `JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR`